# How to communicate from AWS lex to AWS lambda c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I'm trying to build my chatbot using AWS lex and AWS lambda C#.For intent fulfillment
i'm not able to communicate with AWS lambda.[I asked one related questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913959/how-to-troubleshoot-this-aws-lambda-error-an-error-has-occurred-received-erro)

I'm not sure **what are the sequence procedures to communicate to aws lambda from aws-lex**.

Please explain.I guess this may be due to some authentication problem.So it would be helpful if you explain what authentication roles should i have to achieve this and I'm not sure about what event mapping should i use for lex and lambda communication.

Note: AWS lex and AWS lambda works fine independently but not able to communicate each other.

Answer (score 0):

AWS automatically adds the required service roles for Lex to call your lambda function when you connect them in the AWS Console.

If you are creating the bot through the CLI or API, you'll need to create these roles manually. 
More information is available on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-create-role.html) and [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-cli-update-lambda.html) of the AWS Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have AWSServiceRoleForLexBots role attached in your IAM policy.
If you have any plan to connect through any layer, it is advised to have cognito manage identity pool.