# AWS lambda function- 'An error has occurred: Received error response from Lambda: Handled'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

Working on `AWS Lex` for creating a ChatBot and using the `Node.js` in `AWS Lambda`.

> Error: An error has occurred: Received error response from Lambda:
>   Handled

Lambda function:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-east-1'});

    exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

        var eParams = {
            Destination: {
                ToAddresses: [event.currentIntent.slots.Email]
            },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Text: {
                        Data: "Hi, How are you?"
                    }
                },
                Subject: {
                    Data: "Title"
                }
            },

            Source: "abc@gmail.com"
        };
        var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
            if(err) 
            else {

                context.succeed(event);

            }
        });
    };
```

How to get a proper response from Lambda to Lex after successful execution (Email Service works properly). I have tried `context.done();` but it did not worked out.

Edit 1:
Tried adding below response test from [AWS Documentation for LEX](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html) still getting the same error response.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { 

callback(null, { 
"dialogAction": { 
"type": "ConfirmIntent", 
"message": { 
"contentType": "PlainText or SSML", 
"content": "message to convey to the user, i.e. Are you sure you want a large pizza?" 
} 

} 


});
```

Comment: did you get any errors like `Received invalid response from Lambda` but this seems to be a 424 DependencyFailedException from here -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html

Comment: @yashhy yes i di get the error, ye it is 424 DependencyFailedException

Comment: any idea how did you solve this error `424`?

Comment: @yashhy yet to solve, i think need to give permissions to lex using the IAM role

Comment: @yashhy In IAM role there is already permission for Post Text '{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "lex:PostText"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}'

Comment: yes I saw this rule, think its something to solve from Lambda end? because Lex can talk to Lambda, but it says invalid response so something to do on Lambda permissions may be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145099/discussion-between-yashhy-and-sarthak-srivastava).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the *lambda-input-response-format* docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html) `fulfillmentState` property is required in the response.

Other thing is you have to pass either `PlainText` OR `SSML` for the `contentType` in the response. In your case its just `PlainText`.

```
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      callback(null, {
        "dialogAction": {
          "type": "ConfirmIntent",
          "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled", // <-- Required
          "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "message to convey to the user, i.e. Are you sure you want a large pizza?"
          }
        }
    });
```

The above code should solve your problem.

However if you see the req-res in the network tab you would receive HTTP Error 424 which says [DependencyFailedException](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) which says ***"Amazon Lex does not have sufficient permissions to call a Lambda function"*** very misleading.

Comment: Do you know if there's a typescript interface for the input & repsonse? I can't find any anywhere i look